# FastCgiModule - An unknown FastCGI error occurred

Tags: python, iis, deployment, django-project-architect

My django app running on conda environment. I need to deploy the app on IIS server.

To do so I install wfastcgi and configure it.
add Handler mapping I use below path on executable
`C:\Users\sabbir\Anaconda3\envs\sabbir\python.exe|C:\Users\sabbir\Anaconda3\envs\sabbir\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py`
also uncheck Request Restrictions area.
finally watch the tutorial and step by step configure the django app to iis.
now getting below error
[image]

try to provide all access to IIS_IUSRS to respective folders.
Please help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution below:

1. Grant full-access to IUSR to:

   - my webapp folder
   - folder containing the executable to be run (in my case python.exe)
2. In IIS go to -> Authentication -> Select Anonymous Authentication (should be Enabled) -> Edit... -> Choose 'Specific User' set `IUSR`
3. Select root IIS -> Authentication -> Select Anonymous Authentication (should be Enabled) -> Edit... -> Choose 'Specific User' set `IUSR`

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide all access to `IIS_IUSRS` to your python folder.
I had the same error and it worked for me.